# Difference between create! and create when making a relational object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing the Michael Hartl tutorial and the following line made me scratch my head a little:

```
 user.microposts.create!(content: content)
```

Normally, the ! operator means that it modifies the object on which it was called. In this case, however, I found that omitting the ! still modified the user variable AND inserted the micropost in the database. What is the ! operator for in this instance, then?

Answer (score 0):

Bang  operators ( `save!` `create!`) will raise an exception if model is invalid,non bang (`save`, `create`) just returns `false`.
From here http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#when-does-validation-happen-questionmark

Answer (score 0):

The difference is `create!` will raise an exception on failure(which could be due to validations or other callbacks), while `create` returns the object.
With the `create` method, you can get back the `micropost` to check if it there were any errors as such: `micropost.errors`. Whereas you'd deal with an exception in `create!`